# Regex for multiline replacement of strings then placing into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, regex, pandas

Have a kinda odd request. I'm trying to automate some potential SQL queries and need to be able to universally take a text of multiline strings down to a set amount of text (will show in example). After getting this, I want to put it in a pandas dataframe so I can merge it with another to automatically create specific SQL queries (not what I'm asking about here).

The kind of text I'm talking about is similar to this (but a lot more):

```
max(if(serving_id in (25315,25357), option_text, null)) as 'Scheduling',
max(if(serving_id in (25316,25358), option_text, null)) as 'Check-in',
max(if(serving_id in (25317,25359), option_text, null)) as 'Services',
max(if(serving_id in (25318,25360), option_text, null)) as 'Quality of Service',
max(if(serving_id in (25319,25361), option_text, null)) as 'Returns'
```

I would like to be able to easily remove all text before "as" in the above multiline string and then place what's left (i.e. "Scheduling", "Check-in", "Services", etc.) in a pandas dataframe. I've been researching for a while and just can't seem to find a solution for this. Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regular Python, you could use `re.findall` here to get the terms from each line into a list:

```py
inp = """max(if(serving_id in (25315,25357), option_text, null)) as 'Scheduling',
max(if(serving_id in (25316,25358), option_text, null)) as 'Check-in',
max(if(serving_id in (25317,25359), option_text, null)) as 'Services',
max(if(serving_id in (25318,25360), option_text, null)) as 'Quality of Service',
max(if(serving_id in (25319,25361), option_text, null)) as 'Returns'"""
terms = re.findall(r"\s+as\s+'(.*?)',?$", inp, flags=re.M)
print(terms)
# ['Scheduling', 'Check-in', 'Services', 'Quality of Service', 'Returns']
```

You may then use this list to populate your Pandas data frame.

Comment: What if I had say 'Services' and then "It's Quality of service"? How might one select these words when there exists the difference between ' and "? Otherwise that was a fantastic help good sir!